# Get path to ActiveStorage file on Disk storage and S3 storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

How can i get full path to file in ActiveStorage when i use mirror storage settings?

```
S3 Storage (203.4ms) Uploaded file to key: variants/WptxR3NcEEmEiiinyKk7pNdf/b20b002e6479c04dc24ec29300eae0b6031556b740555f161a7a3951d98cedc4
Disk Storage (0.7ms) Uploaded file to key: variants/WptxR3NcEEmEiiinyKk7pNdf/b20b002e6479c04dc24ec29300eae0b6031556b740555f161a7a3951d98cedc4
```

My primary storage is S3, but i want get path from Disc Storage.

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution:

```
item.img.blob.service.mirrors.first.path_for(item.img.blob.key)
```

or like this:

```
ActiveStorage::Blob.service.mirrors.first.path_for(item.img.blob.key)
```

it return full path to img.